# How to select the content of different table in one model

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

What I have:

2 tables, called `Content` and `AboutModel`. In `Content`, I have the following design:

[image]

And the `AboutModel` has the folowing design:

[image]

I have these classes in my code:

```
public class Content : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string WebsiteTitle { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AboutModel> About { get; set; }
}

public class ContentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Content>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Content> b)
    {
        b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}

public class AboutModel : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Content Content { get; set; }
}

public class AboutModelConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AboutModel>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AboutModel> b)
    {
        b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

What I had before adding foreign key was this:

```
    var content = _contentRepository.Query().SingleOrDefault();
```

But when I take the row from the content table, the `About` collection is null. I need help to understand how to access the about contents.

My goal is to have a `file.cshtml` and have a model `Content` and access both `Content` and `About` contents from it and display it on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are few methods to reach that. You can try:

```
var queryResult = myDbContexy.Content.Include(foo => foo.About).SingleOrDefault();
```

Or:

```
var anonymousResult = myDbContext.Content.Select(foo => new {Content = foo, About = foo.About}).ToList();
```

You can also use Join steatment from LINQ but I don't like it ;)

For more you can read about lazy loading in EF.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Appreciate it.